# React - render multiple components using same class - Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, I'm trying to declare a class and use it to render multiple div in different renders, can you please let me know if something is wrong with my approach?

I'm getting an **Invariant Violation** on the second render

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMvOLB?editors=1010)

**Class**

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
    <div className="shopping-list">
        <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Instagram</li>
            <li>WhatsApp</li>
            <li>Oculus</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
    }
    }
```

**Render**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ShoppingList name="Mark" />,
    document.getElementById('cId1'));

    ReactDOM.render(
    <ShoppingList name="Mark" />,
    document.getElementById('cId2'));
```

And in the HTML

```
<div id="id01">Hello World!</div><br /><br />
<div id="cId1" /><br /><br />
<div id="cId2" /><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly HTML doesn't use JSX syntax. If you render a React class somehow to an HTML element, you have to use valid child HTML syntax.

**Change:**

```
<div id="cId1" />
<div id="cId2" />
```

**To:**

```
<div id="cId1"></div>
<div id="cId2"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/trdunya/pen/PLPPbM?editors=1011

**Also;**

You can create DIVs which are same class names in your HTML file.

```
<div class="myItem"></div>
<div class="myItem"></div>


var matched = document.querySelectorAll('.myItem');

matched.forEach(function(item)
{
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ShoppingList name="Mark" />,
    item
  );
});
```